# Check if the array of text column contains string containing phrase

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest, lateral-join

I have a table `customers` with the structure like:

```
id: int
products: text[]
```

I would like to create SQL query that checks if there is a product with name containing phrase "a" but not containing phrase "b" so basically:
`product ILIKE "%a%" AND product NOT ILIKE "%b%"`

If I want to check existance of the element then it's just as simple as using the `@>` operator but here I tried with `UNNEST` and many different approaches and nothing seems to work.

I just want to include given customer row or not depending on this condition. Can you help with that?

I tried things like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customers,
  UNNEST(products) AS product
WHERE
  product ILIKE '%a%' AND product NOT ILIKE '%b%';
```

or

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customers
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(products) AS element
) AS products2 ON TRUE
WHERE
  element ILIKE '%a%' AND element NOT ILIKE '%b%';
```

In theory I could do something like:

```
products::TEXT ILIKE '%a%' AND products::TEXT NOT ILIKE '%b%'
```

But that's an ugly hack that will not always work

Comment: What is wrong with the first query you show?

Comment: You might want to think about a properly normalized model. Don't abuse arrays for things that should be one-to-many relationships

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately I can't change that and I have to deal with array of text here. It's already "normalized" data. I'm not fully responsible for this structure and personally I would just store product ids there and do lookup by product id but that wasn't the thing that happened there :)

Comment: @jjanes it doesn't work :) whenever the first `ILIKE` check returns `true` it will already return this row, it will not even exclude row when the second `ILIKE` check returns `false`. So basically it doesn't do proper condition check on a row. Instead it does check on every sub-row of the unnest result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(c.products) p
              where p like '%a%'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from unnest(c.products) p
                  where p like '%b%'
                 );
```

You *can* do this with a single unnest.  It just seems more complicated:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where (select countif(p like '%a%') = count(*) and
              countif(p like '%b%') = 0
       from unnest(c.products) p
       where p like '%a%' or p like '%b%'
      ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you! :) it works :) It's not super fast as it has to do unnest of products for each condition but it's good enough for now. I wish there are more options of dealing with nested values as in MongoDB. In MongoDB it would be super fast and easy to do. Maybe writing custom function would be faster but I never tried that :). Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: Hmmm interesting second solution. Yep indeed, it looks more complicated but I will try it :). The query is dynamically generated based on conditions so it might not be easy to go with this approach as I'm actually using `SELECT FILTER WHERE(and here I have the actual condition)`. Thanks a lot!